# First instance in string

Tags: php

I have a string, say:

```
www.google.com/tomato.mdm
```

I need to replace tomato with tomaton (add n to it).  My method is to find the . then replace it with n.  .  This didn't work.  Tomato can be many differeny words, so I can't just search for that either...

Is their any way to solve this?

I thought about only replacing it at the first instance from the end, but cannot find a function to do this in the php manuel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach it like this:

```
$string = "www.google.com/tomato.mdm";
$lastDot = strrpos($string, '.');
$newString = substr($string, 0, $lastDot) . 'n.' . substr($string, $lastDot + 1);
```

I use [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strrpos.php) to find the last occurrence of "." in the string. Then I split the string in two parts (using [substr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php)): Everything before the last dot, and everything after it. I then insert "n." between those two parts, which should give the desired result.

A solution using regular expression would be the following:

```
$string = "www.google.com/tomato.mdm";
$newString = preg_replace('/(.*?)(\.[^\.]*)$/', '\1n\2', $string);
```

See [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) and [a regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for more info.

Comment: This seems to replace o. with n. rather than o. with on.  needs the first -1 to not be their, works!

Comment: Yes, I got the "$lastDot - 1" part wrong. But really, given a solution, you should at least be able to debug it a tiny bit, don't you think? This is not a code-writing platform after all...

Comment: Any chance for a quick explanation of the reg ex code?  especially the \1n\2 i've never seen that before...

Comment: \1n\2 just means: Take the first match, then an "n" followed by the second match. The first match is the part of the string that matches (.*?), the second match the part that matches (\.[^\.]*).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Regex to do this

```
 $newStr = preg_replace("#^(www.google.com/[a-zA-z]*)#", '$1n', "www.google.com/tomato.mdm");
```

Comment: If I wanted it to work for any .com, how would I set it to recognise asdjkhasd.com too?  I know it needs a ~ somewhere at the beginning like ~^(.com/[ etc., but can you tell me the correct way to write it please?

Comment: I could spend all night writing regex for you. But I need to wash my hair. I'll leave you with http://regex.powertoy.org/